# jquery each not working propertly while looping through

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, each

I am not able to figure out, why this code (only js) is not running - http://jsfiddle.net/fLEAw/

```
populateList();
populateList: function () {
        var accData = [{ A: "A1" }, { B: "B1"}];

    $.each(accData, function (index) {
            alert(accData[index].Value)
        });

    }
```

Comment: Your objects don't have `Value` property. Actually your code doesn't even reach to that line!

Comment: What can i do to access all the values in accData while looping through?

Comment: @whyAto8: Check my solution. It will alert each Array element Value. :)

Comment: @BlackSheep - Thanks, your input made me realize what went wrong with the code and what I was trying to achieve. Value property is obviously not there, then I realized "A" and "B" need not be different, so I used "Name" in both and it worked. Here the link to working code, which I needed - http://jsfiddle.net/fLEAw/19/

Answer (score 3):

You javascript/jquery code has multiple issues. have a look at this

```
var populateList = function () {
    var accData = [{ A: "A1" }, { B: "B1"}];

    $.each(accData, function (index) {
        for(var value in accData[index]){
            alert(accData[index][value])
        }

    });

}

populateList();
```

I would rather suggest you to rectify the issues your self and ask in comment.

http://jsfiddle.net/fLEAw/3/

Comment: I would like to access the values such as A1,B1 not the index.

Comment: I understood few of the issues you mentioned, thanks for pointing them out. Finally , after reading through all the posts in this, I realized what was wrong in case of my specific requirement and what could be changed, so I did those and its working. - jsfiddle.net/fLEAw/19

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.each` to loop arrays **and** objects:

```
$.each(accData, function(i, obj) {    
  $.each(obj, function(k, value) {
    alert(value);
  });
});
```

I doubt you'll end up using `alert`, you probably want the values to do something with them, so you can put them in an array. Here's an alternative  re-usable approach in plain JavaScript:

```
var values = function(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i in obj) {
    result.push(obj[i]);
  }
  return result;
};

var flatten = function(xs) {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], xs);
};

var result = flatten(accData.map(values));

console.log(result); //=> ["A1", "B1"]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the clarification on usage of $.each, makes it much clear. However I made few changes as per my specific requirement and it worked - jsfiddle.net/fLEAw/19

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
populateList: function () {
```

to

```
function populateList() {
```

Write:

```
populateList();
function populateList() {
    var accData = [{
        A: "A1"
    }, {
        B: "B1"
    }];
    var len = accData.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        $.each(accData[i], function (key, value){
            //key will return key like A,B and value will return values assigned
            alert(value)
        });
    }
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fLEAw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Since your array element is object, try this solution:

```
var populateList = function () {
  var accData = [{ A: "A1" }, { B: "B1"}];

  $.each(accData, function (index) {    
    for(var ele in accData[index]){
      alert(accData[index][ele]);
    }
  });

};
populateList();
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/OQaGIKu/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var accData = [{ A: "A1" }, { B: "B1"}];
$.each(accData, function (index,obj) {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    alert(key + '' + value);
  });
});
```